# Session is not set for the first time on server while working fine on local machine in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, production-environment

I am working on e-commerce project where I am storing products and other related values in session. But SOMETIME session is not set on live while it works fine on local environment. I tried to log value of session but it is null for that instance. Please help me finding solution.

```
    else
        { // This code always run whenever first request is made
         dtProduct = DAL.ShoppingCart.GetProducts(Convert.ToInt64(id)).Tables[0];
         dtProduct.Rows[0]["Qty"] = qty;
         dtProduct.Rows[0]["Total"] = total;
         dtProduct.AcceptChanges();
         }

         Session["product"] = dtProduct;
// Logged session value here, value of qty and total looks correct but session is null
```

**Note** This issue comes rarely and I cannot figure it out as it runs fine on local machine.

Comment: This is hardly solvable with the information you have provided us with. You have to regard the user actions on this. How did he reach this piece of code? Did he reachit by pressing the back button in the browser or can he reach it by direct access, which you did not intend? `IsPostback?` `!IsPostback`? There are probably dozens of ways where storing a session can go wrong

Comment: It executes on button click event, so it will be on !IsPostback. No browser button involved.

Comment: Busy fixing what's been termed "Sessionitis" as an ongoing project. One solution is to simply not use the Session if possible, and it's quite sensible not to.

Comment: When saying Session isn't set - do you mean the Session object itself is null or that Session["product"] returns null?

Comment: on last line I set a session["product"] with dtProduct it working fine local m/c but on production server some time or first time or rare time it give null on session["product"]

Comment: Do you have loadbalancer? What is session configuration on production server? What are the chances that it will not reach line  Session["product"] = dtProduct;? Have analysed web server error logs?

Comment: session type is "InProc" and TimeOut=360 and yes i analysed on web server using error log  on sometime(First Time) dtProduct filled normally while session show null value